# Topological type $x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+ x_3^2+x_4^2 = 0$ in $\mathbb P^4$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let's consider projective variety $V$ given by th equation $x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+ x_3^2+x_4^2 = 0 \ $ in $\mathbb CP^4$.

I was wondering what is the Picard group of $V$ ? Or cohomology ring of $V$ ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you $2$-uply embed $\mathbb{P}^4$ into $\mathbb{P}^{14}$, then this $3$-fold is a hyperplane section of $\mathbb{P}^4$. By the [Lefschetz hyperplane theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_hyperplane_theorem), we deduce that $\mathrm{Pic}(V) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and the betti numbers of $V$ are
$$1,\ 0,\ 1,\ ?,\ 1,\ 0,\ 1.$$

In fact, the middle term is $0$. The reason I know this is that your space is $SO(5)(\mathbb{C})/P$ for an appropriate parabolic $P$, and the complex homogenous spaces have no odd cohomology. There is probably a better way to see this.

The Lefschetz hyperplane theorem tells us that $H^2(\mathbb{P}^4) \to H^2(V)$ is an isomorphism. Letting $\zeta$ be a generator of $H^2$, we see that $\zeta^3$ is twice the fundamental class because $V$ has degree $2$. Poincare duality tells us that $\zeta^2$ must be twice the generator of $H^4$. So integer generators of the cohomology groups are
$$1,\ \zeta,\ \frac{\zeta^2}{2},\ \frac{\zeta^3}{2}$$
and the ring structure is obvious.

Comment: The hyperplane theorem follows from the fact that the complement of the variety in $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is homotopy equivalent to a cell complex whose (real) dimension is $n$. In this case, one can see explicitly that the complement deformation retracts to $\mathbb{R}P^3$, and deduce that $b_3(V) = 0$.

Comment: You can chance coordinates to $a=x_0+ix_1$, $b=x_0-ix_1$, $c=x_2+ix_3$< $d=x_2-ix_3$ to get the equation $ab+cd+x_4^2=0$, which shows that the surface is birational to $\mathb P^3$. I don't know enough about 3-folds to tell if this all implies it is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^3$.

Comment: @Will, the cohomology is not that of $\mathbb P^3$, though, no?

Answer (score 5):

More generally, the cohomology of any smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is described in the paper '[Topology of nonsingular complex hypersurfaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(80)90051-1)' by Kulkarni and Wood.  It depends only on $n$ and the degree of the hypersurface.  (In fact, any two smooth hypersurfaces of the same degree are even diffeomorphic.)  The proof is basically Morse theory.

Comment: The fact you mention is a direct consequence of Ehresmann's fibration theorem (which seems more elementary to me than Morse theory).